# How to export transparent raster plots?

Tags: plotting, export

Is there an easy way to get transparent plots that work with `Save Graphic As` using a compatible file format such as GIF or PNG? I tried `Background->Opacity[0,White]` and `Background->None`, yet the exported PNGs appear to still have a white background.

Comment: If questions could receive bounties, I would give you 500 right now.  I couldn't find the answer to this for my life!  Isn't it ironic I posted it myself 4 years ago?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Instead of using `Save Image As...` you can use the `Export` command, like this:

```
Export["transparent.png", Graphics[Circle[]], Background -> None]
```

For this to work it is important that `Background -> None` is also set inside `Graphics`.  This is the default though so unless you changed it, it should be fine.

Similarly, to convert to an image with alpha channels, use

```
Rasterize[Graphics[Circle[]], "Image", Background -> None]
```

The output of this can be saved even using `Save Image As...`, but this effort needed is the same because of the `Rasterize` function.

Comment: Does the `Save Graphic As` command have a bug?

Comment: @Emre No, it simply doesn't provide a way to change as many options as `Export` does.  The background is white by default when exporting.  You need to change it to transparent, and this is possible with `Export` but not with the simpler `Save Graphic/Image As...`.  People typically need the white background (imagine someone putting a figure with black lines on a black-background webpage), so this is the default.