# Fadingout elements in Graphics

Tags: graphics, opacity

I build complex images using graphics primitives but I want to fade out some so I can place others or text with the transition not being abrupt. This would be easy if we could use `Opacity` inside a `LinearGradientFilling` command, but that only takes colors. [This answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45002/image-fading-from-one-corner-to-the-other/45007#45007) produces transparency in images, but converting that to transparency inside `Graphics` seems quite messy, requiring `Rasterizing` `Image`. My workaround has been to create a `Table` of `Rectangles` of increasing `Opacity` as in the example below. I was hoping a simpler approach might exist, akin to `LinearGradientFilling[{Directive[White,Opacity@1],Directive[White,Opacity@0]}],Rectangle[]`.

Workaround:

```
Graphics[{
  Black, Disk[],
  White,
  Rectangle[{-1, lowPt = -.3}, {(xstart = -.2), highPt = -.1}],
  Table[{Opacity[1 - i/numRectangles], 
    Rectangle[{xstart + 
       i*(width = ((xend = 0) - xstart)/numRectangles), 
      lowPt}, {xstart + (i + 1)*width, highPt}]}, {i, 
    0, (numRectangles = 50) - 1}]
  }]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `LinearGradientFilling` doesn't take `Directives`, but you can include the `Opacity` as part of the color.  Something like `Graphics[{Purple, Rectangle[], LinearGradientFilling[{RGBColor[0, 0, 0, 0], RGBColor[0, 0, 0, 1]}], Rectangle[]}]` should do.

Comment: @ihojnicki Super, exactly what I was seeking! Would you like to write it up as an answer that I would accept?