# Cell ► Convert To ► Bitmap: FrontEndToken for a specific menu item?

Tags: front-end, conversion

[I've seen](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2572) good discussions about the full list of `FrontEndToken`s.

But I could not figure out how to find a specific `FrontEndToken` for a menu item. I'd like to make a `Button` that does what `Cell ► Convert To ► Bitmap` menu item does. I have not seen the word "Bitmap" in the list and not sure if `Button` will work on a selected `Cell`. Any ideas?

Comment: Can't test now but check `ConvertToBitmapPacket` and friends from [13451](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13451/5478)

Comment: @Kuba Thanks, but this `Button["test", FrontEndTokenExecute["ConvertToBitmapPacket"]]` did not work on a selected Cell.

Comment: Those are not tokens but functions which usually work like this: `FrontEndExecute @ ConvertToBitmapPacket [ object]` but the problem is, you never now since they are undocumented and sometimes wrong argument may cause mma crash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the `FrontEndToken` `"SelectionConvert"`. An example of use:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}]
SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Previous, CellContents];
FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken[EvaluationNotebook[], "SelectionConvert", "Bitmap"]];
```

[image: screenshot]

However please beware that FrontEnd's conversion to Bitmap command [looses the alpha channel](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26105/280). As a workaround you could implement your own version of this token with support of the alpha channel, for example as follows:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}]
nb = EvaluationNotebook[];
SelectionMove[nb, Previous, CellContents];
NotebookWrite[nb, 
 ToBoxes@Rasterize[Style[RawBoxes@NotebookRead[nb], Options[nb]], Background -> None]]
SetOptions[nb, Background -> Green]
```

[image: screenchot]