# How do I copy files to the clipboard?

Tags: files-and-directories

Is there a way to mimic the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> for a given file?

I've got *Mathematica* to locate a certain file path, but I don't bother to copy the file in File Explorer (I will do this many times).

Comment: Clipboard? What platform? Windows?

Comment: If you are using OS X I would recommend using apple script (or java script)

Comment: Similar (but not necessarily a duplicate): *[Clipboard with transparency](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26105)*

Comment: To make it more clear what you are asking, can you add an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4):

Building on Todd Gayleys code from the answer that Peter Mortensen pointed to in his comment here is code that I think does what the OP wants: it copies a filename to the clipboard in such a way that you can use Ctrl-V in windows explorer to copy that file to the directory which is shown in the explorer. This code of course is limited to Windows boxes:

```
 Needs["NETLink`"]

 FileNameToClipboard[fname_String] := Module[{dataObject},
   InstallNET[];
   NETBlock[
     dataObject = NETNew["System.Windows.Forms.DataObject"];
     dataObject@SetData["FileDrop", {fname}];
     LoadNETType["System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard"];
     Clipboard`SetDataObject[dataObject]]]
```

I'm not a .NET expert so I don't know if I really am using these object/methods correctly, but for me the code did what I expected...

You may have noticed that one needs to submit a list of strings to the DataOPject's `SetData` method. This will automatically be transformed to a collection/array that the method seems to understand and makes it trivial to provide a list of files to put to the clipboard (as Peter Mortensen has suggested). All you need to change to make this work with a list of filenames is:

1. change the pattern for the definition to 
   `FileNameToClipboard[fname__String]:=...`
2. add another definition:
   `FileNameToClipboard[{fnames__String}]:=FileNameToClipboard[fnames]`

Comment: This is not asked for by the OP, but perhaps a generalisation could be demonstrated (as a variation to the already-existing code) - working for a *list* of files? SetDataObject will probably also work for this, but I have used the .NET function `[Windows.Clipboard]::SetFileDropList($fileSet);` (PowerShell syntax. It may require import of assembly "PresentationCore") from PowerShell. `$fileSet` (PowerShell syntax) must be of type `System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection`. I created an object of that type and used `Add` (there is probably a more elegant way to do it).

Comment: cont': (I don't have access to Mathematica on Windows, only on Raspberry Pi, so I can't test it (but I have tested it from PowerShell and it works as expected).) (*[SetFileDropList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.clipboard.setfiledroplist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)* (MSDN).)

Comment: @PeterMortensen: in fact it is almost trivial to add this, as the SetData method wants a list of strings even for a single filename (which was the only tricky part to find out in the original code). For details how you can make the function work for multiple files see my edit. I don't fully understand the magic which makes this work automatically, but most probably a list of strings is just transfered into something that happens to implement the interface which the method expects...

Answer (score 2):

One way to approach this is to ask the OS to do it. For example, I have a file "test.txt". I can copy this to "test2.txt" using:

```
Run["cp test.txt test2.txt"]
```

and the OS will create (copy) the file to the new name. You can programmatically change the file names and paths in the string. `Run` also works to run other OS functions as well.

You can, of course, also use `CopyFile`.

Comment: It seems that I need to elaborate more... I'm fully aware of `CopyFile`, but my intention is copying the file to clipboard (just like selecting a file and press `Ctrl-V`) for later use in another software.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not very clear and as it stands I'm not sure *Mathematica* is the right tool for the job but your comment regarding `CopyFile` to bill's answer seems to indicate that you wish to copy the *contents* of your file to the system clipboard in which case something like:

```
CopyToClipboard[Import[file, "Text"]]
```

where `file` is the path to your file, may be what you require.  Depending on the contents of your file importing in `"Text"` format may or may not work for you.

As I understand it, this is not quite the same as using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> in File Explorer which is essentially an "intelligent" version of `CopyFile` (i.e. it handles renaming files if pasted in the same directory).