# Unmodified Clipboard content

Tags: interoperability, windows, linux, mac-os-x, clipboard

How do I get unmodified text content from the clipboard?
If you copy the following into the clipboard and use `ClipboardNotebook[]` `\[IndentingNewLine]` is interpreted as `\n`:

```
f[\[IndentingNewLine]]
```

and run

```
FullForm@Catch[
  NotebookGet@ClipboardNotebook[] /. 
   Cell[r_, ___] :> Block[{}, Throw[r, tag] /; True];
  $Failed, tag]
```

> "f[\n]"

Apologies if there is something in alternative to `ClipboardNotebook`,  I haven't found it.

Comment: So actually you need an analog of the MS Word command `Paste Special ► Plain text`, right?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Ideally yes although this question is slightly different.

Comment: @Liam - what happens if you try to paste into a "Code" cell?  If I create a code cell, and just hit Ctrl-v, then I get the same thing as if I manually type `f[\[NewLine]]`

Comment: @JasonB code cell works but it isn't what I am after.  I would like to programatically modify the clipboard.

Comment: You say you need this for Linux but the question is tagged Windows.  Can you correct this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following works for Windows borrowed mostly [from here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26105/clipboard-with-transparency).

```
Needs["NETLink`"];
InstallNET[];
LoadNETType["System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard"];
LoadNETType["System.Windows.Forms.TextDataFormat"];
System`Windows`Forms`Clipboard`GetText[System`Windows`Forms`\
TextDataFormat`UnicodeText]
```

Answer (score 4):

For completion here is how you do it in linux.

```
Import["!xsel --clipboard","Text"]
```

Comment: Note that `xsel` is not installed by default on Ubuntu.

Comment: @Ruslan do you have an alternative recommendation.

Comment: No, it seems all X11 clipboard-related utilities are not installed by default. So you have to just warn the user that he may need to install `xsel` via (for Ubuntu/Debian) `sudo apt-get install xsel` for your answer to work.

Comment: @Ruslan if you post answer I'll give you the bounty I can't give it to myself.

Comment: It wouldn't add anything new: I'm just suggesting you to improve _this_ answer by adding a note about `xsel` (which you use here!) being not by default installed — it can still be easily installed, but the user must actually do this.

Answer (score 2):

And lastly OSX I haven't tested this on OSX yet but believe it should work.

```
Import["!pbpaste","Text"]
```