# How can I copy a figure to the clipboard in SVG?

Tags: .netlink, clipboard, svg-format

I frequently include plots in my emails. The easiest and most reliable way I have found is to just capture a part of the screen using [greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/) (Windows) and paste into the message.

Microsoft recently [added SVG support to Office 2016](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Work-with-SVG-images-in-Microsoft-Office-2016-69f29d39-194a-4072-8c35-dbe5e7ea528c) including Outlook. Hence, it should be possible to embed a nice resolution independent SVG plot created in Mathematica into an Outlook message.

Mathematica doesn't have a "Copy as SVG" menu option. But you can Export to a file, and then import it into you message, however, this is a lot of clicks.

**So the question is**: How to copy as SVG to the clipboard so that the process is simplified?

*Note 1*: a simple:

```
CopyToClipboard[ExportString[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}], "SVG"]]
```

does not work.

*Note 2*: I already have the solution for Windows, so I am more sharing than asking. But there may be better solutions and also with support for other operating systems.

*Note 3*: SVG in email is a good idea in a controlled environment where you know that the recipient has an email client that supports it. For regular, non intranet email, better stick to traditional screenshots.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under Windows, this can be done with NETLink by modifying code published [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26105/clipboard-with-transparency/28280#28280).

```
Needs["NETLink`"]

WriteToClipboardSVG[g_] := 
 Module[{png, strm, dataObject}, InstallNET[];
  png = ExportString[g, "SVG"];
  NETBlock[
   strm = NETNew["System.IO.MemoryStream", ToCharacterCode[png]];
   dataObject = NETNew["System.Windows.Forms.DataObject"];
   dataObject@SetData["image/svg+xml", strm];
   LoadNETType["System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard"];
   Clipboard`SetDataObject[dataObject]]]
```

This was done by opening an svg file with Internet Explorer and examining the examining the clipboard contents using [ClipView tool](http://www.peterbuettner.de/develop/tools/clipview/), and some luck.

So you can now evaluate this:

```
WriteToClipboardSVG[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}]]
```

and paste in Outlook 2016 and nice vector, rescalable plot.