# How to generate images of mathematical equations?

Tags: output-formatting, latex, traditional-form

I would like to use Mathematica to generate nice-looking equations for my presentation on Google Slides (which as far as I know can only be an image an image). What's the best way? To be more concrete, I want to convert the following two equations to something that I can directly copy from a Mathematica notebook and past to a Google Slide.The first example is an executable expression and the second one is the `TraditionalForm` of a string equation (typed using handy Mathematica shortcuts).

Example 1:

```
Integrate[Sqrt[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

Example 2:

```
TraditionalForm["\!\(\*SqrtBox[\(1 + \*FractionBox[\(x\), \
\(2\)]\)]\)"]
```

I am hoping to avoid using third-party websites, taking screenshots, and exporting image files.

Comment: I'd use `TeXForm` followed by [`MaTeX`](https://github.com/szhorvat/MaTeX)

Comment: @yohbs, I will look into MaTex, but it is a third-party software.

Comment: Since you're planning to copy into a slide program, you'll want transparent background, right? So do you agree that this is a duplicate of [Clipboard with transparency](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5364/245), since `Rasterize` in itself can be found in the docs? If not, pleas explain what makes this question different.

Comment: Sorry, I linked only one of two related threads: [Clipboard with transparency](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26105/245) and [How to export transparent raster plots?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5364/245). There are probably other related links, too.

Comment: @mpourrah MaTeX is a good quality piece of software; there should be no reason to avoid it (like certain other Mathematica packages).

Comment: @Jens, it doesn't work on Mathematica 11.1 on Linux (SetData is not defined).

Comment: @QuantumDot I used MaTeX. It is great. Thanks. How can I make images transparent or change the font color?

Comment: @yohbs, Do you know how I can make transparent images with a different font color?

Comment: When you copy the output of `Rasterize[HoldForm[Integrate[Sqrt[x], {x, 0, 1}]]//TraditionalForm,ImageSize->300,Background->None]` and paste it into a graphics program like Gimp on Linux, do you see transparent background? You should...

Comment: @Jens, Nope. The background is white.

Comment: OK, I guess then it requires a Linux specific solution. So I won't vote to close  the question, but unfortunately can't give any better advice...

Comment: MaTeX is maintained by @Szabolcs.  Maybe he has an answer.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to copy an image directly using the mouse, you can try `Rasterize` which generates an image which you can copy/paste directly.

Example 1:

```
eq1 = HoldForm[Integrate[Sqrt[x], {x, 0, 1}]];

Rasterize[eq1 // TraditionalForm, ImageSize -> 300]
```

Output 1:

[image]

Example 2:

```
eq2 = TraditionalForm[
   "\!\(\*SqrtBox[\(1 + \*FractionBox[\(x\), \(2\)]\)]\)"];

Rasterize[eq2, ImageSize -> 300]
```

Output 2:

[image]

**Update Oct 9,2021**

Another option to copy Mathematica expression as graphics directly is to use `MaTeX`. It generates an image, which you can copy as graphics and paste it outside of Mathematica

```
Needs["MaTeX`"]
eq1 = MaTeX[HoldForm[Integrate[Sqrt[x], {x, 0, 1}]],Magnification -> 3]
```

[image]

No need to rasterize it, as `MaTeX` output is already an image.

(ps. this option was also mentioned in comments above. This require having `MaTeX` installed and also a latex compiler and the other requirements it needs. But everything it needs is available free software. ).

Comment: Is it possible to make the output images transparent?

Comment: The image qualities are not good. Is it possible to convert equations to graphics?

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised nobody pointed out that (in the Windows Front End at least), you can simply select the expression (in Traditional Form), go to the Edit menu and do Copy As.../Bitmap and then paste it into your slides.  For some reason (and this has been the case for many years), this option is not present in the right-click/Copy As... options.  This also works with plots or any other kind of graphics.[image]

Comment: You said, `(in Traditional Form),` This works for any selected expression. It does not have to be in tradition form.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use

```
Style[HoldForm[eq1 = Integrate[Sqrt[x], {x, 0, 1}]], Large]
```

[image]

Then right-click on the right bracket of the output and `Save Selection As` one of several possible formats.  Alternatively, follow the desired expression by, for instance,

```
Export["C:\\Temp\\test.png", %]
```

Likewise,

```
Style[HoldForm[eq2 = TraditionalForm[Sqrt[1 + x/2]]], Large]
```

[image]

`Style` is quite flexible and can give the desired expression quite a range of appearances.

Comment: This cannot be directly copied, hence doesn't satisfy the question requirements.